# Detect when Stripe elements payment form is loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, angular, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe elements to load a payment form, but sometimes it takes 5-10 seconds for the form to load completely.

Is there a way to detect when the form is completely finished loading, so I can display a loading animation/image until then?

console.log('Stripe API Script loaded');
this.stripe = Stripe('..........');

```
  const create_customer_response = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("create_customer_response"));
  const client_secret = create_customer_response["intent"]["client_secret"]
  const options = {
    clientSecret: client_secret,
  };

  elements = this.stripe.elements(options);

  const payment = elements.create('payment');
  const paymentElement = document.getElementById('payment-element');

  if (paymentElement) {
    payment.mount(paymentElement);
    
    this.isPaymentElementMounted = true; // Set the flag to true when the payment element is mounted
    console.log('Payment element mounted successfully.');
    console.log("this.stripe ", this.stripe);
    console.log(elements);
    this.spinner.hide();
  } else {
    console.error('#payment-element not found in the DOM. Make sure your template is correct.');
  }
}
scriptElementStripe.onerror = () => {
  // console.log('Could not load the Google API Script!');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is working solution. :)

this.stripe = Stripe('.......');

```
  const create_customer_response = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("create_customer_response"));
  const client_secret = create_customer_response["intent"]["client_secret"]
  const options = {
    clientSecret: client_secret,
  };

  elements = this.stripe.elements(options);

  const payment = elements.create('payment');
  const paymentElement = document.getElementById('payment-element');

  if (paymentElement) {
    payment.mount(paymentElement);

    // Listen for the 'ready' event
    payment.on('ready', () => {
      this.isPaymentElementMounted = true; // Set the flag to true when the payment element is ready
      console.log('Payment element is ready.');
      console.log("this.stripe ", this.stripe);
      console.log(elements);
      this.spinner.hide();
    });


  } else {
    console.error('#payment-element not found in the DOM. Make sure your template is correct.');
  }
}
scriptElementStripe.onerror = () => {
  // console.log('Could not load the Google API Script!');
}
```